# How to pass ASP.NET Core collection to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I'm completely new in .NET core world. I faced a problem with converting `@foreach (var item in Model.Products)` into JavaScript array holding JSON product object (id, name). I tried solutions found in Stack Overflow and in some blogs, but each of them ends up in from server status 500 to ignored assignment.

Wrong attempts:

`var yourjavascriptArray = <%=new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(cSharpArrayName);%>;`

`var inData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Products));`

Code that is used:

Controller:

```js
public IActionResult Index(string searchkey)
{
  ... 
  return View(new Models.ProductSearcherModel() { SearchKey = searchkey, Products = prods 
});
```

Index.cshtml:

```js
@foreach (var item in Model.Products)
{
   //how to assign Model.Products to js array?
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your attempts. We don't want to waste your time and ours suggesting solutions you've already tried and found to be lacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to assign Model.Products to js array?

You can try to use **JsonHelper.Serialize** Method, like below.

```
@section scripts{
    <script>
        var products = @Json.Serialize(Model.Products);
        console.log(products);
    </script>
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Besides, if you'd like to retrieve data and do operation on JavaScript client side, you could achieve it using ajax etc.

Answer (score 1):

This feels like the wrong approach.

I would probably generally recommend a separate ajax call to a controller to retrieve the json. But without seeing the code that you have it's difficult to say more.